# what does_is_drive_letter macro do?

Tags: c

This macro is found in "dosname.h" from coreutils.

```
 # define _IS_DRIVE_LETTER(C) (((unsigned int) (C) | ('a' - 'A')) - 'a' \
 <= 'z' - 'a')
```

Could someone explain it for me?

Comment: [This internal macro assumes ASCII, but all hosts that support drive
      letters use ASCII](http://sourceforge.net/p/pimd-ng/git/ci/1dd3c80702f5f48bebf979b2966ee6f33d430625/tree/lib/dosname.h)

Comment: What do you think it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It checks, if the given character is a valid letter to be used to name a drive (e.g. the "C" in "C:\Something" is usually used to name the main hard drive) in MS-DOS-based operating systems.

It's an efficient way to check, if the character matches the regular expressions `[a-zA-Z]` (English alphabet letters, both upper-case and lower-case).

It does so by first eliminating the differences between lower-case and upper-case letters using the bitwise "or" operation `|`. In the general case a conditional addition would be necessary: Add the distance between the lower-case `'a'` and the upper-case `'A'`, if the ASCII code is below the one of `'A'`. But since in ASCII the difference between a lower-case character and its corresponding upper-case value is always exactly 32 (= 2^5 = 100000b) and the range of lower-case letters is smaller than 32, we see that the only difference in the binary representation of a lower-case letter and its corresponding upper-case letter is the 6th bit, e.g. 1000001b == A and 1100001b == a. So we can convert upper-case letters to lower-case letters by setting that 6th bit using the `|` with 32 (== 'a' - 'A') as second operand. This will do weird stuff to all other characters that aren't letters, but it won't ever convert them to a letter. This trick works more efficiently (without having to use a condition).

Then it is checked, if the character (that is now lower-case, if it was an upper-case letter before) is between `'a'` and `'z'`. This is done by subtracting `'a'` from the character and checking, if the result is smaller than the number of characters. That works because in ASCII the English characters of the same case are defined as a continuous sequence.

Comment: Thank you I get the point .Could you give me more explanation concerning the code.

Comment: Just did, I hope it helps.

Comment: @mayailias is mastov's answer not good enough for your homework?

Answer (score 3):

```
# define _IS_DRIVE_LETTER(C) (((unsigned int) (C) | ('a' - 'A')) - 'a' \
 <= 'z' - 'a')
```

`('a' - 'A')` is the lowercase flag.

`(C) | ('a' - 'A')` set the lowercase flag in C. (now C can be between 'a' and 'z' but can be anything else also).

`'z' - 'a'` compute the range between letters 'a' and 'z' (so 25, for letter 'a'(0) to letter 'z'(25)).

The comparison `<=` checks to verify is 'C' converted to lowercase and offset to 0 beginning at letter 'a' is between 0 and 25, so between letters 'a' and 'z' (so, **is it a valid drive letter for MS-DOS**).